# Difficulty opening pylab image from buffer object

Tags: python, matplotlib

Working within web2py, using python 2.7, I've got something like this going on:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') 
import pylab
import Image
import io

temp_data = {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,4,5]}

pylab.plot(temp_data['x'], temp_data['y'])
img_buffer = io.BytesIO()
pylab.savefig(img_buffer, format = 'png')
Image.open(img_buffer)
```

This raises

> IOError - "cannot identify image file"

Trying this on my server's python installation (no web2py) produces the same error. Trying this on my workstation's python shell gives (apparently, the Image module clashes with pylab):

```
AccessInit: hash collision 3: for both 1 and 1
```

Any ideas as to what's going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must rewind the `img_buffer` after writing to it and before reading from it.

```
pylab.savefig(img_buffer, format = 'png')
img_buffer.seek(0)
Image.open(img_buffer)
```